# Rest client in NancyFX?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, nancy, webhttp

How can i consume rest based web services using nancyfx? does nancy provides inbuilt rest client like httpclient or restsharp ?

I have tried using restsharp and httpclient for the same but not able to find any ways for nancyfx library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NancyFX is a web framework like MVC / Web API, it's not a client library for making web requests.

You would still use HttpClient or RestSharp for that.